# Error : malloc():memory corruption in Comparison function for sort

Tags: c++, stl

The following code is to print the largest number from a list of integers. I am getting:

```
 *** Error in `./a.out': malloc(): memory corruption: 0x0000000000bfe070 ***
```

on the list (20 zeros):

```
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

However in the above if I put some non zero elements I do not get the error.

This is my code for the  comparison function :

```
bool comp(int a,int b)
{
     if(a == b)
         return true;
     stringstream ss;
     ss << a;
     string a1 = ss.str();
     stringstream sss;
     sss << b;
     string b1 = sss.str();
     int i = 0;
     int l1 = a1.length();
     int l2 = b1.length();
     while(i < l1 && i < l2)
     {
         if(a1[i] > b1[i])
             return true;
         if(a1[i] < b1[i])
             return false;
         i++;
     }
     if(l1 == l2)
         return true;
     if(l1 < l2)
         if(b1[l1] > a1[0])
             return false;
         else
             return true;
     else
         if(a1[l2] > b1[0])
             return true;
         else
             return false;
}
```

I am using the stl

```
 sort(nums.begin(),nums.end(),comp);
```

where nums is a vector of integers.

**EDIT 1 :**

This is the entire code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>

using namespace std;
bool comp(int a,int b)
{
if(a == b)
    return true;
stringstream ss;
ss << a;
string a1 = ss.str();
stringstream sss;
sss << b;
string b1 = sss.str();
int i = 0;
int l1 = a1.length();
int l2 = b1.length();
while(i < l1 && i < l2)
{
    if(a1[i] > b1[i])
        return true;
    if(a1[i] < b1[i])
        return false;
    i++;
}
if(l1 == l2)
    return true;
if(l1 < l2)
    if(b1[l1] > a1[0])
        return false;
    else
        return true;
else
    if(a1[l2] > b1[0])
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
void largestNumber(vector<int>& nums)
{

sort(nums.begin(),nums.end(),comp);
/*string s = "";
vector<int>::iterator it = nums.begin();
while(it != nums.end())
{
    stringstream ss;
    ss << *it;
    s = s+ss.str();
    it++;
}
return s;*/
}



int main()
{
int n;
cin>>n;
vector<int> arr(n);
for(int i = 0;i<n;i++)
    cin>>arr[i];

largestNumber(arr);/*
string s = largestNumber(arr);
cout<<s<<endl;*/
}
```

Comment: Why are you converting the integers to strings and comparing strings, rather than simply comparing the integers directly?

Comment: Try running your program with valgrind. It is very useful in finding errors where a program is inadvertently writing/reading from areas it shouldn't. The error you are getting means that the program has written to portion of the heap that wasn't allocated to the user.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your comp function violates the [strict weak ordering rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering). Sort requires that the compare function should meet the strict weak ordering rule. If that promise is broken, so is the promise of std::sort to behave correctly. Infact when I compile this under MSVC (VS2015) I get a assertion failure that the compare function doesn't meets the ordering condition.
For eg this line:

```
 if(a == b)
     return true;
```

clearly violates the condition. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218591/c-stdvector-stdsort-infinite-loop) post for more insights.

BTW if you just want to sort the integers in lexicographic order you can just do

```
bool comp(int a,int b)
{
    return to_string(a) < to_string(b);
}
```

If you want the equivalent of "bigger number first", just swap the < with >

Comment: For the record, it doesn't happen in Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Version 11.0.50727.1.

Comment: @MuratKarakuş Were you compiling under the debug mode?

Comment: No, under release mode but I have used application and it is working.

Comment: @MuratKarakuş: "works on my machine" doesn't mean it's correct. Returning `true` on equality obviously violates the [requirements for a comparison function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare).

Comment: @MuratKarakuş Under release mode the asserts are no-op. :)

Comment: My original code did not have this. I got the error and so added this. But in either case I still get the error.

Comment: @Blastfurnace I agree, the application may not do what is should do but what I meant from "works on my machine" is that it doesn't cause a memory corruption failure.

Comment: @midi Another line where this gets broken: if(l1 == l2)
    return true;
Now I can either keep pointing these, or you editing your code to meet the criteria that sort requires/editing your question to express your intent in the compare function.

Comment: @MuratKarakuş: I have actually seen an invalid comparison function cause `std::sort` to modify memory past the end of a `std::vector`. Violating a function's preconditions can easily lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: @bashrc thnx a lot :)

Comment: @Blastfurnace thanks, you made a good point. I have missed that.

Comment: @bashrc consider [3,32] lexicographically 32 is bigger so the ordering would be [32,3] but this does not give the largest number.

Comment: @midi Well for me it does: http://ideone.com/1y4Abx Can you share your code where it fails?

Comment: @bashrc I had to find the largest number(by concatenating elements) from the list. so [32,3] gives 323 whereas the largest number would be 332. So lexicographical sort might not work

Comment: @bashrc well my algo is also wrong. I'll have to recurse further.. better option is to form two separate strings (a1+b1 and b1+a1) and then compare them lexicographically. But this question was not about the algo, rather about the comp function violating strict weak ordering rule as you had pointed out :)

Answer (score 0):

I have used your `comp` function and created a sample case-study to examine the error. However, I didn't get any error for the `array of zeros` case. Please check sample program.

## Error

However, below scenario causes run-time error.

```
// Pay attention: Array stores numbers in descending order.
// If we stored in ascending order, there won't be a problem.
for(int i=20; i>0; ++i)
    v.push_back(i);
```

I hope this would be helpful to find solution.

## Sample program

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

bool comp(int a,int b)
{
     if(a == b)
         return true;
     stringstream ss;
     ss << a;
     string a1 = ss.str();
     stringstream sss;
     sss << b;
     string b1 = sss.str();
     int i = 0;
     int l1 = a1.length();
     int l2 = b1.length();
     while(i < l1 && i < l2)
     {
         if(a1[i] > b1[i])
             return true;
         if(a1[i] < b1[i])
             return false;
         i++;
     }
     if(l1 == l2)
         return true;
     if(l1 < l2)
         if(b1[l1] > b1[l1-1])
             return false;
         else
             return true;
     else
         if(a1[l2] > a1[l2-1])
             return true;
         else
             return false;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    vector<int> v;
    for(int i=0; i<20; ++i)
        v.push_back(0);
    sort(v.begin(), v.end(), comp);
    copy(v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well This is strange... I have every thing else commented out, but I still have the error.

Comment: @midi I have found an error and pointed out with sample program, please check it.

Comment: I just checked your code.. Segmentation error on my machine. ubuntu 64bit

Comment: @midi maybe because of your case, could you please share the full code. Btw, I have found an error in your implementation, what do you think about it?

Comment: l1 is the length of the string a1 and l2 is the length of the string b1. if l1 is 1 and l2 is 2 then b1 has length 2 and so both b1[0] and b1[1] would be valid

Comment: @midi yes, you are right, I will take my answer down. Btw, I think you should have named b1 to b2 or a2 to create a link between l2. It would be easier to read :)

Comment: Sorry fot that.. I was in a hurry while writing this code :)